# Compute the "lower contour" of a set of segments in the plane in `O(n log n)`

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, computer-science

Suppose you've a set `s` of horizontal line segments in the plane described by a starting point `p`, an end point `q` and a `y`-value.

We can assume that all values of `p` and `q`are pairwise distinct and no two segments overlap.

I want to compute the "lower contour" of the segment.

We can sort `s` by `p` and iterate through each segment `j`. If `i` is the "active" segment and `j->y < i->y` we "switch to" `j` (and output the corresponding contour element).

However, what can we do, when no such `j` exists and we find a `j` with `i->q < j->p`. Then, we would need to switch to the "next higher segment". But how do we know that segment? I can't find a way such that the resulting algorithm would have a running time of `O(n log n)`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [sweep line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm) is an efficient way to solve your problem. As explained previously by Brian, we can sort all the endpoints by the x-coordinate and process them in order. An important distinction to make here is that we are sorting the *endpoints* of the segment and not the segments in order of increasing starting point.

If you imagine a vertical line sweeping from left to right across your segments, you will notice two things:

- At any position, the vertical line either intersects a set of segments or nothing. Let's call this set the active set. The lower contour is the segment within the active set with the smallest y-coordinate.
- The only x-coordinates where the lower contour can change are the segment endpoints.

This immediately brings one observation: the lower contour should be a list of *segments*. A list of points does not provide sufficient information to define the contour, which can be undefined at certain x-coordinates (where there are no segments).

We can model the active set with an `std::set` ordered by the y position of the segment. Processing the endpoints in order of increasing x-coordinate. When encountering a left endpoint, `insert` the segment. When encountering a right endpoint, `erase` the segment. We can find the active segment with the lowest y-coordinate with `set::begin()` in constant time thanks to the ordering. Since each segment is only ever inserted once and erased once, maintaining the active set takes O(n log n) time in total.

In fact, it is possible to maintain a `std::multiset` of only the y-coordinates for each segment that intersects the sweep line, if it is easier.

The assumption that the segments are non-overlapping and have distinct endpoints is not entirely necessary. Overlapping segments are handled both by the ordered `set` of segments and the `multiset` of y-coordinates. Coinciding endpoints can be handled by considering all endpoints with the same x-coordinate at one go.

Here, I assume that there are no zero-length segments (i.e. points) to simplify things, although they can also be handled with some additional logic.

```
std::list<segment> lower_contour(std::list<segment> segments)
{
    enum event_type { OPEN, CLOSE };

    struct event {
        event_type type;
        const segment &s;
        inline int position() const {
            return type == OPEN ? s.sp : s.ep;
        }
    };

    struct order_by_position {
        bool operator()(const event& first, const event& second) {
            return first.position() < second.position();
        }
    };

    std::list<event> events;
    for (auto s = segments.cbegin(); s != segments.cend(); ++s)
    {
        events.push_back( event { OPEN, *s } );
        events.push_back( event { CLOSE, *s } );
    }
    events.sort(order_by_position());

    // maintain a (multi)set of the y-positions for each segment that intersects the sweep line
    // the ordering allows querying for the lowest segment in O(log N) time
    // the multiset also allows overlapping segments to be handled correctly
    std::multiset<int> active_segments;

    bool contour_is_active = false;
    int contour_y;
    int contour_sp;

    // the resulting lower contour
    std::list<segment> contour;

    for (auto i = events.cbegin(); i != events.cend();)
    {
        auto j = i;
        int current_position = i->position();
        while (j != events.cend() && j->position() == current_position)
        {
            switch (j->type)
            {
                case OPEN:  active_segments.insert(j->s.y); break;
                case CLOSE: active_segments.erase(j->s.y);  break;
            }
            ++j;
        }
        i = j;

        if (contour_is_active)
        {
            if (active_segments.empty())
            {
                // the active segment ends here
                contour_is_active = false;
                contour.push_back( segment { contour_sp, current_position, contour_y } );
            }
            else
            {
                // if the current lowest position is different from the previous one,
                // the old active segment ends here and a new active segment begins
                int current_y = *active_segments.cbegin();
                if (current_y != contour_y)
                {
                    contour.push_back( segment { contour_sp, current_position, contour_y } );
                    contour_y = current_y;
                    contour_sp = current_position;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!active_segments.empty())
            {
                // a new contour segment begins here
                int current_y = *active_segments.cbegin();
                contour_is_active = true;
                contour_y = current_y;
                contour_sp = current_position;
            }
        }
    }

    return contour;
}
```

As Brian also mentioned, a binary heap like `std::priority_queue` can also be used to maintain the active set and tends to outperform `std::set`, even if it does not allow arbitrary elements to be deleted. You can work around this by flagging a segment as removed instead of erasing it. Then, repeatedly remove the `top()` of the `priority_queue` if it is a flagged segment. This might end up being faster, but it may or may not matter for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

First sort all the endpoints by x-coordinate (both starting and ending points). Iterate through the endpoints and keep a `std::set` of all the y-coordinates of active segments. When you reach a starting point, add its y-coordinate to the set and "switch" to it if it's the lowest; when you reach an ending point, remove its y-coordinate from the set and recalculate the lowest y-coordinate using the set. This gives an O(n log n) solution overall.

A balanced binary search tree such as that used to implement `std::set` generally has a large constant factor. You can speed up this approach by using a binary heap (`std::priority_queue`) instead of a set, with the lowest y-coordinate at the root. In this case, you can't remove a non-root node, but when you reach such an ending point, just mark the segment inactive in an array. When the root node is popped, continue popping until there is a new root node that hasn't been marked inactive already. I think this will be about twice as fast as the set-based approach, but you'll have to code it yourself and see, if that's a concern.

Comment: I've edited my question and provided some code. I'm still unsure how exactly you want to use the three differently sorted containers. Maybe you can take my code and edit it according to your idea.